# Error: The type T cannot be used in GenericTypeMatcher - Expression expected

Tags: java, swing, assertj

I tried to implement a generic method that will return a GenericTypeMatcher (provided by AssertJ Swing) of type parameter T. You can see the method [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W1e1.png).

The problem is that I get an `Expression expected` error for the supported type of the GenericTypeMatcher with the `Class<T>`.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted instead of images. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `GenericTypeMatcher` accepts a `Class<T>` argument.
 You're passing the type definition instead, which is invalid.

```
private static <T extends Component> GenericTypeMatcher<T> getMatcher(final Class<T> clazz) {
   return new GenericTypeMatcher<T>(clazz) {
      @Override
      protected boolean isMatching(final T object) {
         return ...
      }
   }
}
```

Usage

```
YourClass.getMatcher(YourComponent.class);
```